# Shape of data changing in Tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

The shape of my data after the mapping function should be (257, 1001, 1). I asserted this condition in the function and the data passed without an issue. But when extracting a vector from the dataset, the shape comes out at (1, 257, 1001, 1). Tfds never fails to be a bloody pain.

The code:

```
def read_npy_file(data):
    # 'data' stores the file name of the numpy binary file storing the features of a particular sound file
    # as a bytes string.
    # decode() is  called on the bytes string to decode it from a bytes string to a regular string
    # so that it can passed as a parameter into np.load()
    data = np.load(data.decode())
    # Shape of data is now (1, rows, columns)
    # Needs to be reshaped to (rows, columns, 1):
    data = np.reshape(data, (257, 1001, 1))
    assert data.shape == (257, 1001, 1), f"Shape of spectrogram is {data.shape}; should be (257, 1001, 1)."
    return data.astype(np.float32)

spectrogram_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((specgram_files, labels))

spectrogram_ds = spectrogram_ds.map(
                    lambda file, label: tuple([tf.numpy_function(read_npy_file, [file], [tf.float32]), label]),
                    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

num_files = len(train_df)
num_train = int(0.8 * num_files)
num_val = int(0.1 * num_files)
num_test = int(0.1 * num_files)

spectrogram_ds = spectrogram_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
specgram_train_ds = spectrogram_ds.take(num_train)
specgram_test_ds = spectrogram_ds.skip(num_train)
specgram_val_ds = specgram_test_ds.take(num_val)
specgram_test_ds = specgram_test_ds.skip(num_val)


specgram, _ = next(iter(spectrogram_ds))
# The following assertion raises an error; not the one in the read_npy_file function.
assert specgram.shape == (257, 1001, 1), f"Spectrogram shape is {specgram.shape}. Should be (257, 1001, 1)"
```

I thought that the first dimension represented the batch size, which is 1, of course, before batching. But after batching by calling `batch(batch_size=64)` on the dataset, the shape of a batch was `(64, 1, 257, 1001, 1)` when it should be `(64, 257, 1001, 1)`.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Although I still can't explain why I'm getting that output, I did find a workaround. I simply reshaped the data in another mapping like so:

```
def read_npy_file(data):
    # 'data' stores the file name of the numpy binary file storing the features of a particular sound file
    # as a bytes string.
    # decode() is  called on the bytes string to decode it from a bytes string to a regular string
    # so that it can passed as a parameter into np.load()
    data = np.load(data.decode())
    # Shape of data is now (1, rows, columns)
    # Needs to be reshaped to (rows, columns, 1):
    data = np.reshape(data, (257, 1001, 1))
    assert data.shape == (257, 1001, 1), f"Shape of spectrogram is {data.shape}; should be (257, 1001, 1)."
    return data.astype(np.float32)

specgram_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((specgram_files, one_hot_encoded_labels))

specgram_ds = specgram_ds.map(
                    lambda file, label: tuple([tf.numpy_function(read_npy_file, [file], [tf.float32, ]), label]),
                    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

specgram_ds = specgram_ds.map(lambda specgram, label: tuple([tf.reshape(specgram, (257, 1001, 1)), label]),
                             num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```